# How to shift values of given array by moving first value to the last C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was struggling on how to move the first value to the las in order like shown in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wfjd.jpg)

What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rotate(int A[], int n = 5)
{
    int x = A[n - 1], i;
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        A[i] = A[i -1];
    }
    A[0] = x;
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, i;
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[5]);

    cout << "Given array is \n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << A[i] << ' ';

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        rotate(A, n);

        cout << "\nStep " << j << " --> ";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << A[i] << ' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to do this shift in 5 separate steps, given that your `rotate` function already achieves the same purpose in just 1 step?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is still quite "C" like. Here is an example that hopefully will teach you some C++ coding :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// passing arrays is easier using std::vector/std::array (no need to pass size seperately)
void rotate(std::vector<int>& values)
{
    // using algorithm's std::swap you can better show WHAT you are doing
    // vector and array also have a size() method so you don't
    // have to use "C" style sizeof tricks.
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size() - 1; ++n)
    {
        std::swap(values[n], values[n + 1]);
    }
}



int main()
{
    // prefer std::vector (or std::array) in C++. Not "C" style arrays
    std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

    rotate(values);

    // use range based for loop if you can.
    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```